# Column not found after update db

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, flyway

I'm new to java . i've two questions . i'm using flyway and h2 db i added two file sql one of them to create table with two columns like that

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
id bigint auto_increment NOT NULL, 
name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and the other is to alter new column like that

```
ALTER TABLE contacts
ADD COLUMN contacts Varchar(255);
```

1- i used flyway.migrate worked fine but i faced mismatch so i used flyway.repair() is that normal to use it every time ?

2- when i wrote statment sql for executing insert sql command like that

```
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO contacts(name,contacts) VALUES('ABC','ABC@yahoo.com')");
```

i got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "CONTACTS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO contacts(name,contacts) VALUES('ABC ','ABC@yahoo.com') [42122-173]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `AFTER` in your second sql file.

```
ALTER TABLE contacts
ADD COLUMN contacts Varchar(255) AFTER name;
```

Comment: thanks for replying , it worked but execuse me , should i write after to make db know where it will add the new column ?

Comment: can you help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801000/no-data-is-available

Comment: I would be surprised if this was the actual solution, as the [`AFTER`-clause is **optional**](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_add). I'd sooner expect something like transaction visibility of metadata changes.

Comment: yes, that is make me wonder really , but i tried both commands with after and without it and worked with it