# JDBC ResultSet - No data is available

Tags: java, exception, jdbc

I'm new to java, i tried to print all data in the table

```
    Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
    String sql ="INSERT INTO contacts(name,email)VALUES('ABC','ABC@yahoo.com')";
    stmt.execute(sql);
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT*FROM contacts");
    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
```

and got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-173]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `rs.next()` before calling `rs.getString("...")`.

```
...
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts");

while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
}
```

---

If you're expecting only 1 row, then you can also do:

```
...
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts");

if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping, it worked but why while didn't work ?

Comment: @user5520049 You don't show any `while` loops in your question...

Comment: sorry i forgot to write it , i used while and got contacts
id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :id is :Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-173]  but when i used if it worked